# Is there a right to keep and bear ammunition?

Tags: united-states, second-amendment

The Second Amendment protects the right to keep and bear *arms*. Does this include ammunition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right to bear arms wouldn't even make sense without the right to also possess ammunition, so any conscionable interpretation of 2A must include both.

As evidence, consider that if it were constitutional to ban all ammunition, a bunch of jurisdictions would already have done so. But even the most draconian of laws don't go that far.

Comment: It's not helped that compared to manufacturing firearms, it's way cheaper to make your own bullets.  Prohibition would be easier to enforce.

Answer (score 2):

This is not definitively decided. A number of states forbid large capacity ammunition magazines, and [the law in California](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_California_Proposition_63) was overturned as unconstitutional. In one challenge, a federal judge ruled that the law violated the second amendment and the 3-judge panel upheld that decision, but the [full court overturned](https://cdn.ca9.uscourts.gov/datastore/opinions/2021/11/30/19-55376.pdf) the decision, so it is not a violation of the 2nd amendment, in the 9th Circuit. New Jersey has a similar law, [which has been challenged](https://www.supremecourt.gov/DocketPDF/20/20-1507/188524/20210825131114398_2021.08.25%20ANJRPC%20Cert%20Reply%20FINAL.pdf) at the level of the Supreme Court. We don't know for sure, at this point.

Comment: There'd be a lot less question if the laws being contested banned all possession of magazines whatsoever.